# Cache replacement Policy : LFU

Tags: caching

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

#include "cache.h"

namespace
{
  std::map<CACHE*, std::vector<uint64_t>> lfu_counts; // Add a data structure to store LFU counts
  std::map<CACHE*, std::vector<uint64_t>> last_used_cycles; 
}

void CACHE::initialize_replacement() {
  last_used_cycles[this] = std::vector<uint64_t>(NUM_SET * NUM_WAY);
  lfu_counts[this] = std::vector<uint64_t>(NUM_SET * NUM_WAY, 0); // Initialize LFU counts to 0
}

uint32_t CACHE::find_victim(uint32_t triggering_cpu, uint64_t instr_id, uint32_t set, const BLOCK* current_set, uint64_t ip, uint64_t full_addr, uint32_t type)
{
  auto begin = std::next(std::begin(::last_used_cycles[this]), set * NUM_WAY);
  auto end = std::next(begin, NUM_WAY);

  // Find the way with the lowest LFU count
  auto victim = std::min_element(begin, end, [this, set](const uint64_t& a, const uint64_t& b) {
    return lfu_counts[this][set * NUM_WAY + a] < lfu_counts[this][set * NUM_WAY + b];
 });
   assert(begin <= victim);
  assert(victim < end);
    return std::distance(begin, victim); // Calculate the distance between begin and victim
 
//   return static_cast<uint32_t>(std::distance(begin, victim)); // cast protected by prior asserts
}

void CACHE::update_replacement_state(uint32_t triggering_cpu, uint32_t set, uint32_t way, uint64_t full_addr, uint64_t ip, uint64_t victim_addr, uint32_t type, uint8_t hit)
{
  // Mark the way as being used on the current cycle
  if (!hit || access_type{type} != access_type::WRITE) {
    ::last_used_cycles[this].at(set * NUM_WAY + way) = current_cycle;
    // Increase the LFU count for the used way
    lfu_counts[this][set * NUM_WAY + way]++;
  }
}


void CACHE::replacement_final_stats() {}
```

this is the C++ code for the least frequently used replacement policy but i am not very sure whether it is correct or not.... because i am not getting expected output

I need to run this code on 5 tracer files so it should give me 5 different output txt files containing the data of hits and misses of different levels of cache. but I am getting only 4 . Could someone explain why?

Comment: WIthout seeing the "tracer files", or how you are using this code on them?